# What is the best practice when setting initial state if i use redux in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm trying to move app to redux(newbie). I have this code and I'm confused a little bit what is the best practice to set initial state. For example this is code

```
class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      cityName: '',
      nameOfCity:'',
      weatherDescription:'',
      windSpeed:'',
      temperature:'',
      maxTemperature:'',
      minTemperature:''
  };
}

updateInfo(results){
  this.setState({
      nameOfCity: results.city.name,
      weatherDescription: results.list[0].weather[0].description,
      windSpeed: results.list[2].wind.speed,
      temperature: results.list[0].main.temp,
      maxTemperature: results.list[0].main.temp_max,
      minTemperature: results.list[0].main.temp_min
  });
   }

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h2>Weather App</h2>
    </div>
    <p className="App-intro">
      To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
    </p>
      <FormContainer label="Name of the city:" updateInfo={this.updateInfo.bind(this)}/>
      <WeatherInfo
          nameOfCity={this.state.nameOfCity}
          weatherDescription={this.state.weatherDescription}
          windSpeed={this.state.windSpeed}
          temperature={this.state.temperature}
          maxTemperature={this.state.maxTemperature}
          minTemperature={this.state.minTemperature}
      />
  </div>
  );
}
}
```

And what is the best practice when you use redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Redux you shouldn't need to use react state in this way. As in all application data. All of this state should be moved to the central redux store and populated via actions and reducers. You then use the `connect` method of `react-redux` to map the store state to the props of the component.

For your app `updateInfo` should be an action creator and have a reducer which will reduce the form data sent in this action into the state. Because the redux state is mapped to the props of you component the view will update as you would expect by displaying `this.props.weatherDescription` or whatever data you like.

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.md) to get a fuller idea of how to structure a react redux app. There is also a video series on getting started with redux [here](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux)

Answer (score 1):

first you need to setup redux in your app then set initial state in redux store
Please go through this link

> http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Examples.html